# php switch array key with subelement key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key, switch-statement

I would like to switch the main keys(0,1,2) of an array with a subelement key(user_id).

For example, from this array:

```
    array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["num_products_user_by_ref"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(2) "77"
    ["reference"]=>
    string(3) "E49"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["num_products_user_by_ref"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(3) "526"
    ["reference"]=>
    string(3) "E49"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["num_products_user_by_ref"]=>
    string(2) "38"
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(3) "346"
    ["reference"]=>
    string(3) "E49"
  }
}
```

I need :

```
array(952) {
  [77]=>
  array(2) {
    ["num_products_user_by_ref"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["reference"]=>
    string(3) "E49"
  }
  [526]=>
  array(3) {
    ["num_products_user_by_ref"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["reference"]=>
    string(3) "E49"
  }
  [346]=>
  array(3) {
    ["num_products_user_by_ref"]=>
    string(2) "38"
    ["reference"]=>
    string(3) "E49"
  }
```

Every user_id could contains more than 1 pair num_products_user_by_ref/reference.
I remember that there is a function to achieve this (ksort?) associated to a custom function to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$out = array();     
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    $out[$value['user_id']]["num_products_user_by_ref"] = $value["num_products_user_by_ref"]; 
    $out[$value['user_id']]["reference"] = $value["reference"];
}
print_r($out);
```

Your question showed a structure that doesn't seem to fit with your comment "Every user_id could contains more than 1 pair num_products_user_by_ref/reference." So, here's another version that allows for that possibility:

```
$out = array();     
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    $entry = array("num_products_user_by_ref" => $value["num_products_user_by_ref"],
                    "reference" => $value["reference"]);
    $out[$value['user_id']][] = $entry;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [77] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [num_products_user_by_ref] => 1
                    [reference] => E49
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [num_products_user_by_ref] => 5
                    [reference] => E49
                )
        )
    [526] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [num_products_user_by_ref] => 9
                    [reference] => E49
                )
        )
    [346] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [num_products_user_by_ref] => 38
                    [reference] => E49
                )
        )
)
```

Here's another version for those who don't like traditional loops:

```
$out = array();
array_walk($arr, function($e, $k) use(&$out){
    $entry = array("num_products_user_by_ref" => $e["num_products_user_by_ref"],
                    "reference" => $e["reference"]);
    $out[$e['user_id']][] = $entry;
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Pé, there are really no way to achieve it whitout loops?

Comment: @ArnaudNcy Besides a loop, the only other option would probably be `array_walk`, but that's essentially a loop anyway, and I believe it's less efficient. I just noticed your comment about multiple entries per user, so I'll update my answer.

Comment: Perfect! thank you very much for the interest you have brought to my question!